# boost wave or spirit for glsl parser

Tags: c++, boost, glsl, boost-spirit

I want to parse a custom tag in OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) code, which is a very C-like language.  A general use case will look like this:

```
#version 150

@bind ProjectionMatrix
uniform mat4 projMatrix;
@bind ViewMatrix
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

in vec4 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * position;
}
```

I want to do this to 'annotate' variables with a `@bind` tag, so that I can connect them to variables in my actual application (i.e. i can pass values from my app to glsl).  So I would parse the glsl code, and whenever I find a `@bind` tag, I then parse the `ProjectionMatrix` (or `ViewMatrix`) as the variable to pass from c++ to glsl, and then parse the `projMatrix` (or `viewMatrix`) as the variable that should store the value sent from c++.

What I'm wondering is - would it be better to use boost wave or spirit for this?  those are the two libs I'm looking at to solve this.

I have got boost wave lexer working, in that it iterates over all tokens.  so I would have to write code to parse the returned tokens and look for patterns.

I'm not sure exactly how i'd do this with spirit, but it seems like it's a more  robust lexer/parser.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Boost.Wave is a C++ preprocessor. GLSL isn't C++. And while it does have some token similarities to C++, odds are good that it's going to choke the moment it hits the first line of your GLSL. Since the first line of your GLSL is `#version`, which is not a legal C++ preprocessor directive. The first line of your GLSL *is* `#version`, right?

Comment: yup - but that's not a problem.  I just override the 'unknown directive' method for boost.wave, and accept glsl directives.  But I'm not worried about pre-processing in terms of directives, I'm concerned more about the best way to parse the glsl code and pick out certain patterns.

Comment: Jarret, why don't you tell us what the concrete task is you want to establish. I can "guess" you a grammar that I think fits the two line sample you write, but I'd have no clue what you want to get out of the parsing

Comment: hey @sehe, sorry I was not clear enough.  I've tried to edit my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still unsure how you expect us to know what glsl is all about. So I can really only do a broad *guess* as to the actual input format.

Let's say I interpret this in the simplest way I see fit (without being ridiculously useless):

```
annot       = "@bind" >> ident >> eol;
declaration = 
   omit [ +(ident >> !char_(';')) ] // omit the type, TODO
    >> ident >> ';' >> eol;
```

Now, all we need is a simple way to ignore full lines until we find one that contains an annotation:

```
ignore = !annot >> *(char_ - eol) >> eol;
```

<sup>*If you wanted to ignore `@bind` lines that aren't followed by a declaration, you may want to use `!combi` instead of `!annot`.*</sup>

This is just a starter for you. Also, not that all this 'implicit' definition of *ignorable* lines may induce a lot of backtracking. So don't expect topnotch performance.

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Map;

template <typename It>
  struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, Map(), qi::blank_type>
  {
    grammar() : grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        ident = lexeme [ alpha >> *alnum ];
        annot = "@bind" >> ident >> eol;
        declaration = 
            omit [ +(ident >> !char_(';')) ] // omit the type, TODO
            >> ident >> ';' >> eol;

        ignore = !annot >> *(char_ - eol) >> eol;

        combi = annot >> declaration;
        start = *ignore >> combi % *ignore;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(combi);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(ignore);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(declaration);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(annot);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(ident);
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, qi::blank_type> ignore;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), qi::blank_type> ident, declaration, annot;
    qi::rule<It, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(), qi::blank_type> combi;
    qi::rule<It, Map(), qi::blank_type> start;
  };

template <typename It>
void test(It f, It l)
{
    grammar<It> p;

    Map mappings;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::blank, mappings);

    if (ok)
    {
        for (auto it = mappings.begin(); it!=mappings.end(); ++it)
            std::cout << "'" << it->second << "' annotated with name '" << it->first << "'\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cerr << "warning: remaing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}

int main()
{
    const std::string input(
        "#include <reality>\n"
        "@bind VarName\n"
        "uniform int myVariable;\n"
        "// other stuff\n"
        "@bind Var2Name\n"
        "uniform int myVariable2;\n");

    test(input.begin(), input.end());
}
```

This will print:

```
'myVariable2' annotated with name 'Var2Name'
'myVariable' annotated with name 'VarName'
```

See verbose (DEBUG) output **live on [liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1lQLQ4%240)**

Comment: hey @sehe, sorry, I didn't know you didn't know what glsl was.  i tried to make that a little clearer in the question.  Thanks for the answer, I think it will work!